# Add the New order email notification attachment to the vendor email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

In WooCommerce, I use woocommerce-product-vendors as multi vendor plugin. After checkout I receive as admin an a new order email notification with the attachment (uploaded file).

But the vendor receive the same email but without the attachment. I need that the vendor receive the attachment too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this code with a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order`** filter hook:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'adding_vendor_email', 10, 2);
function adding_vendor_email( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient; // (Optional)

    // Your code or conditions to get the vendor email (if needed)

    $recipient .= ",vendor@yourdomain.com";
    return $recipient;
}
```

You will need to customize this custom hooked function to get the email dynamically…

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works

> You could also use **`woocommerce_email_attachments`** filter hook… see [**this related thread**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258353/woocommerce-email-attachments-filter-arguments)

Comment: Thanks a lot Loic for your support i'm really recognizing you are the best thanks.